# Push Notification shows every time on app launch

Tags: android, notifications, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I've followed a tutorial and implemented GCM push notification on my existing app. I've set `Main` activity to show notification. User receives a notification, clicks on it and notification display on `Main` activity. The problem is on app relaunch it shows notification every time.

**Main Activity**

```
public void registerGCM() {
    ....
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        ServerUtilities.register(context, uname, uemail, regId);
    }
}
```

Im calling this function on `onCreate` of `Main` activity to register app. This process is working fine.

Here's the BoradcaseReceiver code in `Main` activity outside of onCreate function.

```
private final BroadcastReceiver mHandleMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver()
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        String newMessage = intent.getExtras().getString(EXTRA_MESSAGE);
        WakeLocker.acquire(getApplicationContext());
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "New Message: " + newMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        WakeLocker.release();
    }
};
```

It should only show notification once when user clicks it (this works fine), but its also showing notification every time use launch the app. How do i prevent this?

Please let me know if im not clear enough. 
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If i understood you correctly your missing this [**documentation**](http://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/navigation.html)

add this attrs into your manifest between activity tags for your result activity i.e MainActivity (for more information check link above)

```
android:excludeFromRecents="true"
android:launchMode="singleTask"
android:taskAffinity=""
```

i can't see your notification receiver class so make sure you are setting resultIntent flags like

```
resultIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
```

note: *dont forget to give every notification an unique id*

Comment: I appreciate the comment. I'll get back to you after making the edits you mention. Thanks!

Comment: I've edited the code as you explained, im still having the same issue. Here's the updated code:
Manifest:
`<activity android:label="MyAppName" android:name="Main" android:excludeFromRecents="true"                 android:launchMode="singleTask"                  android:taskAffinity="" />`

GenerateNotification:
`notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);`

Can you please explain a bit how can i pass unique id to a notification?

Comment: can you share the complete code that you are register and receiving the notificiation

Comment: This is the tutorial i've used. I've just moved the MainActivity part of tutorial to my app Main Activity. If you share your email i'll email you the Main activity code.

Comment: can't see you email, is it publicly shared ?